# Not receiving release notes and destination in appcenter

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-app-center

Using the method of API as mentioned in the Appcenter document.

Gave the correct destination (groupID), but still not uploading the release to groups. I see it is empty.
Also the release notes,how and where do we pass it in the CURL commands. (we had an option, notes flag in HockeyApp)

Answer (score 0):

Before distributing releases to groups please add one more command :

```sh
curl -X PATCH \
"https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/releases/Release_Id" \
-H "accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-API-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
-d '{ "distribution_group_name": "provide group name", "distribution_group_id": "provide group id", "release_notes": "your notes", "mandatory_update": true }'
```

above URL will pass release notes and releases to Groups

then perform below action as per the doc:

```sh
curl -X POST \
"https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/JoshuaWeber/APIExample/releases/2/groups"
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'X-API-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-d '{ "id": "10d82aa2-8449-499f-b6d3-44a855058eca", "mandatory_update": false, "notify_testers": false }' \
```